# XAMPP MySQL stuck at attempting to start MySQL service

Tags: mysql, cmd, xampp

I had checked my computer and there is mysql running, I not sure it that SQL financial using it or others program, and I have no permission to access it. So, I tried to running 2 mysql with different port.

XAMPP MySQL already changed to port 3307 and when I manually start it by

```
mysqld --defaults-file=mysql\bin\my.ini --standalone --console
```

it stuck at starting as process xxxx.....

any idea what happen and how can I trace or solve the problem?

Comment: you could check the mysql service in services. Stop that service and restart the xampp process

Comment: so cannot run 2 mysql in sametime?

Comment: yes you cannot run two instance.